# Why does my PBI not show on the Kanban if it has child PBIs/Bugs?

Tags: tfs, scrum, tfs-2015, alm

We're still fine-tuning our ALM process using TFS 2015 Update 1 On-Prem. We are using the standard SCRUM template and we display bugs on the backlog, along with requirements. Bugs are reported by the business and go through the same level of analysis as PBIs in that they will contain child tasks:

[image]

Now for PBIs, when a tester is testing the PBI and discovers a bug with it (which needs to be fixed as part of this sprint), they will create a bug as a child to the PBI. This keeps them together on the task board. 1 PBI may have many bugs and these may be worked on by different people. These child bugs will have child tasks.

The process mostly works but on the Kanban board, the child bugs are shown, the parent PBIs are not. Why not? and how can I work-around this? I can link them differently but we want them to stay together on the boards.

[image]

[image]
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It feels like you're really mixing and matching the two supported scenarios here.

Personally I prefer not to create Bugs as part of the sprint (to me they're not really bugs if they haven't made it out of the iteration) and often it's used as a communication mechanism instead of dev & test working closely together.

If you want something on the board under the PBI/Bug, you could use a Task Work Item (or a custom type) and then use the funky card colouring on the board to look for a tag to signify that it's an in-sprint bug/issue.

[Highlight work items based on custom criteria](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/work/customize/customize-cards)

Comment: That makes sense. You're probably right about mixing up the bugs. I might see about getting them to create a task with a specific tag. Thanks